# Как убрать notification у woocommerce?

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce, wordpress-плагины

Есть страница checkout, где пользователь видит что он добавил себе в корзину,видит итоги заказа и кнопку "подтвердить заказ", но там есть так-же один блок " 
payment notification", могу ли я его как-то убрать? Оставить только кнопку
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Приложите код, я уберу, за вас!

Comment: @misdeed не уберёшь, ты ВП не знаешь.

Comment: Убери/настрой региональные настройки

Comment: @SeVlad я много  чего не знаю, но мне не трудно разобраться)

Comment: @misdeed вот когда разберёшься с ВП и WC - тогда приходи что-то советовать

Comment: @SeVlad, ладно, хорошо, пэхэпэшник! только не бомби, пожалуйста

Comment: @misdeed  чтобы знать ВП - знаний php не достаточно. А местами они и не нужны вовсе. Вот как в данном случае напр.Так что прекращай умничать, иди  про перловку спрашивай, а к ВП не подходи  :)

Comment: @SeVlad хорошо, хорошо, пэхэпышник)0)) всё, не подойду больше. Ты меня убедил

Comment: меня интересует не костыльный метод, может какой-то хук есть
разве эта штука не дефолтная у woocommerce?
это мой первый опыт с этим плагином, еще не разобрался

Comment: Где эти региональные настройки?

Comment: В настройках WC

Answer (score 0):

Три варианта:

1. Настроить платежи по умолчанию в *Настройка -> Доставка -> Местоположения за пределами других ваших зон*
2. Отредактировать *checkout\payment.php* (строка 35)
3. Заменить/добавить свою надпись через functions.php или сниппеты в хуке *woocommerce_no_available_payment_methods_message*